# tree cross validation of tree package in r

Tags: r, tree, cross-validation

Does anyone knows how the `cv.tree` function of tree package in r, works?
The default is set to 10 folds, but the results show 8 tree models instead of 10:

[image]

Moreover if i set 5 folds the results show 8 models:
[image]

The code i used is below:

```
library (MASS)
library(tree)
set.seed (1)
train = sample (1: nrow(Boston ), nrow(Boston )/2)
tree.boston =tree(medv~.,Boston ,subset =train)
summary (tree.boston )
cv.boston =cv.tree(tree.boston,K=10)
cv.boston
```

Thank you

Comment: `K` is the number of folds of the cross-validation, which is not the output itself but the way the output is got. Crossvalidation works such that the trained data will be splitted in K parts, trained and predicted on the part left of the train set to see how well the model generalizes. For more information, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

Comment: Correct and the cross-validation process is repeated k times, so if we have 10-fold cross validation, 10 tree models should be returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eight things that are displayed in the output are not the folds from the cross-validation. The documentation for `cv.tree` says of the output:

> **Value**
>
> A copy of FUN applied to object, with component dev replaced by the cross-validated 
>   results from the sum of the dev components of each fit.

Since you did not specify the `FUN` argument to `cv.tree`, you get the default `prune.tree`. What is the output of `prune.tree`? The documentation says:

> Determines a nested sequence of subtrees of the supplied tree by
>   recursively "snipping" off the least important splits, based upon the
>   cost-complexity measure. prune.misclass is an abbreviation for
>   prune.tree(method = "misclass") for use with cv.tree.

Notice that your tree has exactly 8 leaves.

```
plot(tree.boston)
text(tree.boston)
```

[image: Plot of tree]

`prune.tree` is showing you the deviance of the eight trees, snipping off the leaves one by one.  `cv.tree` is showing you a cross-validated version of this. Instead of computing the deviance on the full training data, it uses cross-validated values for each of the eight successive prunings.

Compare the deviance in the outputs of just using `prune.tree` with the cross validated deviance.

```
prune.tree(tree.boston)

$dev
[1]  3098.610  3354.268  3806.195  4574.704  5393.592  6952.719 11229.299
[8] 20894.657

cv.tree(tree.boston, K=5)

$dev
[1]  4768.281  4783.625  5718.441  6309.655  6329.011  7078.719 12907.505
[8] 20974.393
```

Notice that the cross-validated values are rather higher at every step. Just using `prune.tree` tests on the training data and so under-reports the deviance. The cv values are more realistic.

Comment: Great explanation thank you!
What do you mean "it uses cross-validated values for each of the eight successive prunings"?
k-fold cross validation is used to 8 tree-paths separately?

Comment: Yes,  exactly.  It uses cross-validation eight times.